# Notebook formatting - easier descriptions for equations and results?

Tags: output-formatting, coding-style

When I do computations in mathematica, I generally try to make it readable for myself-in-the-future.  This can be a cumbersome task in mathematica, where it often requires me to switch betwee a text cell, then back to an equation cell (or two), over and over again, to be able to label what a given equation/result is.

e.g.

```
(text:) This is the equation for ... .... ...
In[517]:= 2 + 2
Out[517]= 4
```

over and over again.  Is there anyway to make mathematica produce output like the following?

```
In[517]:= 2 + 2  This is the ... Equation
Out[517]= 4      The resulting value ...
```

Comment: You can add comments to input lines using (* ... *), but doctoring output will turn the formatting into input style.

Comment: You may want to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135572/2-column-documents-in-mathematica/) and the answers provided there. Basically, what you want seems to be possible by using inline cells. You can use cell options `Evaluatable->True` and `CellEvaluationFunction` to tweak the evaluation so that it only evaluates the input code part of your larger cell.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin -- What a great idea.  I missed it first time around.

Comment: Thanks @LeonidShifrin, that does provide the resulting look I wanted, but its again far too laborious to be convenient

Comment: Tangentially related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1047/121

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An interesting problem.

Trivially one could use `Print` like this:

```
Print[2 + 2, Spacer[50], "this is a note"]
```

> ```
> 4      this is a note
> ```

But that is hardly a usable syntax.  Looking deeper into the system one observes that `(* comments *)` are stripped during parsing so those are out of reach without prohibitive contortions.  Strings however are inert objects that could serve as comments.  I propose this:

#### Version 2

```
$note = Null;

$PreRead =
  Replace[#,
    RowBox[{body__, ";", note_String?(StringMatchQ[#, "\"*\""] &)}] :>
     ($note = Style[ToExpression@note, Italic, Red]; RowBox[{body}])
  ] &;

$PrePrint = 
  If[$note =!= Null,
     # &[Row[{Pane@#, Spacer[50], $note}], $note = Null],
     #
  ] &;
```

(This code uses a new `` Global` `` symbol `$note` -- in practice it may be better to place this in a different context to prevent collisions and allow for e.g. `` ClearAll["Global`*"] `` without issue.)

**Comments are made as Strings ending a line and following semicolon.**

This has at least the limitation of the way that *Mathematica* reflows text in standard Input cells.  Here the last comment, "Graphics", wraps to the next line:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When using this implement it may be preferable to use a cell style that does not reflow, such as Code:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`Pane` in the `$PrePrint` function is to handle a case such as the last line above; without it `Graphics` objects are incorrectly downsized.

Note that in version 2, because labeling is handled with `$PrePrint`, the functionality of `Out` remains intact allowing `%^2` in the example and maintaining Output cell labels.

Comment: Mr. Wizard is still clearly THE Wizard +1

Comment: @Jagra Thanks for the kind words.  If this method is put into use it would probably be better to use a method besides `Print` as this doesn't create any actual `"Output"` cells.  Consider this answer, at present, a proof of concept.  Better output formatting and integration into the `In[]` / `Out[]` system are yet to be done.

Comment: This is quite nice!  Thanks @Mr.Wizard.  As you point out -- creating actual "Output" is pretty important, so I haven't accepted this as 'the answer' just yet.

Comment: @zhermes okay, but you like the input syntax?  If you do I'll see what I can do about proper output, otherwise I'll go back to the drawing board.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, first - yes!  The syntax looks great!  Second - I just played with it a little more, and I don't think there is actually any 'Output' functionality that I'm missing (i.e. nothing that I generally do seems to require specific 'Output' cells).  Unless you have an example of somewhere where this might be a big problem --- I think its a done deal.

Comment: @zhermes Try e.g. `2+2; "comment"` and next line `% + 1` -- the output should be `5` but it is `1 + Null` because the actual `Out` assignment was `Null` (this is how `Print` works).  I'll try to improve this behavior soon.

Comment: That was the only functionality I could think of, and I generally don't need that.  I'm satisfied!  Thanks @Mr.Wizard

Comment: @zhermes thanks for the Accept.  I'll still be updating this answer in time as *I'm* not satisfied yet.  Thanks for the interesting question.

Comment: @zhermes The function is complete, at least for now.  Please let me know if you find any bugs or other problems.

Comment: Awesome.  This should be a feature in mathematica... who do you write a letter to?

Comment: This is really great for my homework! I changed it to print before by changing to `Row[{ Pane@#, $note, Spacer[5]}]` because I usually note things as "This $quantity is ". I also fixed the reflow problem by changing [LineBreakAdjustments](http://goo.gl/gUVTH) for my Input style in my stylesheet to `{1,2,7,0,1}` The first and third parameters come out as the most important parameters and if you've ever been dissatisfied with Mathematica reflowing this may make you happy. Setting c from 7 to 4 won't break the string, and if you want to allow breaking in the string set it to 3 to 0. [fixed]

Comment: For those interested in using the modification @dmikalova made to @Mr.Wizard's code to get the text to print before, the correct substitution is  `Row[{ $note, Spacer[5], Pane@#}]`, since this gives text -- space -- math.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard :  I just posted a question about how to generalize your very nice code — to allow text to be input either before, or after, or both — here:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134498/how-to-generalize-this-combined-preread-preprint-code

Answer (score 3):

The best I can think of gets a bit cumbersome, but if you did everything this way one could deal with it consistently:

```
In[517]:= {2 + 2, "The resulting value ...'} (* This is the ... Equation *)

Out[517]= {4, The resulting value ...}

In[518]:= %[[1]] (* To use just the value *)

Out[518]= 4
```

Again quite cumbersome.

Comment: Yeah, still cumbersome --- but it's definitely a step in the right direction!  Thanks @Jagra