# Hyperlink shrink the image, how to make the image become original size

Tags: formatting, hyperlink

I found that

```
Hyperlink[im, "something", ImageSize -> 800]
```

The `ImageSize` only add some borders of my `im`.

How to make my im become the actual size?

You can try a big image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short, but the answer, is to fix image size:

```
Hyperlink[Image[pic, ImageSize -> 800]]
```

Answer (score 2):

My [preferred](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11987/121) method to prevent this kind of automatic resizing is to wrap the element in [`Pane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pane.html).
This has the advantage that it does not require one to set a specific value with `ImageSize`.

```
im = Image[RandomReal[1, {300, 400, 3}]];

Hyperlink[im, "something"]
Hyperlink[Pane @ im, "something"]
```

[image]

[image]