# Set all output to be of specific form

Tags: notebooks, output-formatting, formatting, output

I want every output expression in a notebook to use `//PowerExpand` and also to format numbers as scientific.  Is there a way to do this without explicitly calling `ScientificForm[]` and `//PowerExpand` on every input?

i.e. I want to be able to enter

```
In: 4.3*^-5*Sqrt[M]*(L*n^2)^{3/4}
Out: {0.000043 \Sqrt[M] (L n^2)^(3/4)}
```

and instead get,

```
Out: 4.3e-5 M^(1/2} L^(3/4} n^(3/2)
```

<strike>[Aside: is there a way to make mathematica ***never*** use radical symbols, and to use exponents instead?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48869/use-only-exponents-no-radicals-in-output-expressions)</strike>

Comment: I suggest re-posting your final line as a separate question.  It seems both interesting and potentially difficult.

Comment: Great idea, [I've posted a new question here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48869/use-only-exponents-no-radicals-in-output-expressions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With

```
$PrePrint = ScientificForm@PowerExpand@# &
```

You would get the desired output. To return to normal just type:

```
$PrePrint =.
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is working on a new notebook, but when I put it into my existing notebook, and re-run my cells - they keep the same format.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are using a variation of my comments-in-output code from [Notebook formatting - easier descriptions for equations and results?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11961/notebook-formatting-easier-descriptions-for-equations-and-results/11987#11987)  The variation you are using does not actually produce any formal output; it merely prints the evaluated form as a side-effect.  Despite its name `$PrePrint` *does not affect the lines produced by `Print`*, as these are not considered output.

You can either add `ScientificForm` and `PowerExpand` to your modified `$PreRead` function:

```
$PreRead = Replace[#, 
    RowBox[{body__, ";", note_String?(StringMatchQ[#, "\"*\""] &)}] :> 
     Print[ScientificForm @ PowerExpand @ ToExpression@RowBox@{body}, Spacer[50], 
      Style[ToExpression@note, Italic, Red]]] &;
```

Or as I would prefer you can add it to my original code:

```
$note = Null;

$PreRead =
  Replace[#,
    RowBox[{body__, ";", note_String?(StringMatchQ[#, "\"*\""] &)}] :>
     ($note = Style[ToExpression@note, Italic, Red]; RowBox[{body}])
  ] &;

$PrePrint = 
  If[$note =!= Null,
    # &[Row[{Pane@#, Spacer[50], $note}], $note = Null],
    #
  ] & @ ScientificForm @ PowerExpand @ # &;
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  This made everything work perfectly.  I'm giving the 'accepted' answer to eldo as he did most appropriately answer the question I (naively) asked.

Comment: @zhermes You're welcome, and no problem.