# Use only exponents (no radicals) in output expressions

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, output

Radical symbols ($\sqrt{\,\,\,\,}$) are the devil.  Is there any way to get mathematica to never use them, and instead express everything as an exponential?

i.e. I want

```
In[1]:= Sqrt[x]
```

to give $x^{1/2}$ instead of $\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: Does `$Post=(#/.Power[x_,Rational[a_,b_]]:>HoldForm[x]^HoldForm[(a/b)])&` do what you want?

Comment: @rasher You should be using `Defer` rather than `HoldForm` so that output can be used as input.  Also I don't think holding `x` is necessary.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Yeah, just threw out an idea - this kind of thing is something I've never had any real need to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I would choose to use [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MakeBoxes.html) and [`Defer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Defer.html) for this:

```
MakeBoxes[a_^Rational[1, x_], fmt_] := ToBoxes[a^Defer[1/x], fmt]
```

Now:

```
-Sqrt[a - bar]
```

> ```
> -(a - bar)^(1/2)
> ```

This also catches cases that use [`RadicalBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RadicalBox.html):

```
x^(1/3) // TraditionalForm
```

> `x1/3`

`Defer` is used to allow the output to be used as input.  An alternative is [`Interpretation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interpretation.html) but that seems like overkill here.

Instead of `MakeBoxes` definition you could use `$PrePrint`, assuming it is not already in use or you will append a rule to an existing definition.  It is clean but gives you less control over specific formatting.

```
$PrePrint = # /. a_^Rational[1, x_] :> a^Defer[1/x] &;
```

If these miss some cases or change things that should not be changed (undetermined), you could instead intercept all box conversions and replace `SqrtBox` and `RadicalBox`:

```
lhs : MakeBoxes[arg__] /; ! TrueQ[$sqrtReplace] :=
     Block[{$sqrtReplace = True},
  lhs /. {
    SqrtBox[a_] :> SuperscriptBox[a, RowBox[{"1", "/", "2"}]],
    RadicalBox[a_, x_] :> SuperscriptBox[a, RowBox[{"1", "/", x}]]
   }
 ]
```

This should be avoided if possible as it is a costly operation.  (It will add overhead to all output generation.)

Comment: This looks great in a new notebook!  How can I append this rule to my previous $PrePrint (i.e. [the previous thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48847/1065))?

Comment: @zhermes I suggested `MakeBoxes` so that that would not be necessary, but if you wish you could use: `$PrePrint = 
  If[$note =!= Null, # &[Row[{Pane@#, Spacer[50], $note}], $note = Null], #] &[
    ScientificForm@PowerExpand@# /. a_^Rational[1, x_] :> a^Defer[1/x]] &;`.  Incidentally I made a mistake in the prior answer which I will now correct.

Comment: Also, it looks like this (the solution from your comment, not using the 'interception') doesn't work for radicals in the denominator.  Is this an issue with catching a '-1/2' instead of '+1/2' ?

Comment: @zhermes You're right, I'd need to allow for `Rational[-1,2]` there.  That also raises the question of which format you prefer: `foo/-Sqrt[a - bar]` could render as either `-(foo/(a - bar)^(1/2))` or `-(a - bar)^(-(1/2)) foo`.

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the `FullForm`, you will see that it already uses the exponential form:

```
Sqrt[x] // FullForm
(* -> Power[x, Rational[1, 2]] *)

x^(1/2) // FullForm
(* -> Power[x, Rational[1, 2]] *)

Sqrt[x] === x^(1/2)
(* -> True *)
```

Comment: I would argue that it doesn't use exponential form, it uses verbose-descriptions-form :)