# How to make N apply to exponent?

Tags: numerics, code-generation

For example, I want to covert `y + Sqrt[x]` to `y + x^0.5`, where `y` and `x` can be very complicated expressions.

Edit:
Here's why I want to do this.
I want to generate C++ expression from *Mathematica* expression. The method I can think of is to do some sort of recursion down the expression tree. I don't want to have things like 1/2 or 2/3 anywhere in the expression (but rather, 0.5 or 0.66666666666666667 is fine). However, the function `N` doesn't apply to the exponent.

Moreover, if this walking down the expression tree can recognize `Sqrt`, it would be even better.  However, `Head[Sqrt[x]]` is `Power`, not `Sqrt`.

Edit:
Problem solved:  use `` SymbolicC`CExpression `` and `` SymbolicC`ToCCodeString ``, together with some macros.

Comment: While it's possible to do, you'd probably get more useful responses if you explained *why* you want to do this.

Comment: Your title has nothing to do with your question.  What are you asking here?

Comment: possible dup http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48869/use-only-exponents-no-radicals-in-output-expressions

Comment: Be aware introducing the floating point `0.5` changes an exact expression into one that is considered to be approximate. The linked question addresses the display formatting which is probably what you *really* want.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: To give an example related to @george2079's comment, note that for a symbolic `x`, `(x^0.5)^2 == x` does **not** evaluate to `True`, and even evaluates to `False` on some numeric input (e.g. `x -> I`).

Comment: 你的问题和N完全无关啊？`N`不会把`Sqrt[x]`变成`x^(0.5)`

Comment: N[6/5*(3+x)] gives 1.2(3.+x).  Something is holding the same conversion for the exponent in, say, Power[x, 3/2].  I want to know how to turn that off.

Comment: One possibility is to use `SetPrecision[expr,MachinePrecision]` on your expression.

Answer (score 2):

Use the substitution rule as follows:

```
myExpression /. Sqrt[x___] -> x^0.5
```

Example:

```
myExpression = Cos[t] + Sin[y] + Sqrt[a y + Tanh[z] + u^3]
```

Cos[t] + Sin[y] + (u^3 + a y + Tanh[z])^0.5