# How to group these output as one?

Tags: output-formatting, parallelization

```
(* toy example *)
myfun[x_, y_: 0] := Block[
    {ans, myplot, summary},
    Print["The first value is ", x];
    Print["The second value is ", y];
    Print["Their sum is ", x + y];
    summary = {#1, "=", #2} & @@@ 
    Transpose[{{"x", "y"}, Round[{x, y}, 0.001]}];
    Print[Grid[summary, Alignment -> {Left, Right, Center}]];
    myplot = Plot[Sin[z], {z, -10, x}];
    Print[myplot];
];

myfun[1, 2]
```

Runs fine.

But I want to do Parallel computing, like this

```
Parallelize[
    {myfun[1, 2],
    myfun[1, 4],
    myfun[2, 5]
    }

]
```

Then the output becomes this:

[image]

Which does not make any sense.

How would I change the code, so that the output keeps in the same order (for each call of `myfun`), but executes each of the function calls still run in Parallel?

**Update:**

So if I want to avoid using `Print`, I tried a bit like this:

```
myfun[x_, y_: 0] := Block[{ans, myplot, summary, res},
Reap[

Sow[Print["The first value is ", x], res],
Sow[Print["The second value is ", y], res],
Sow[Print["Their sum is ", x + y], res]


];

summary = {#1, "=", #2} & @@@ 
Transpose[{{"x", "y"}, Round[{x, y}, 0.001]}];


Reap[
Sow[Grid[summary, Alignment -> {Left, Right, Center}], res]
];

myplot = Plot[Sin[z], {z, -10, x}, ImageSize -> Medium];

Reap[Sow[myplot, res]][[2]]
];
```

So Reap collects all the `res` term? I dont think I fully understand how this works in a bit piece of code.

Thanks!

Comment: Get rid of `Print` alltogether and group all relevant returns for a function call in one `Grid`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Yves said replace `Print` with `List` output.  Here is an example using [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) along with `Block` and *Mathematica* 10 notation for [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html).  (It would be better to avoid `Print` from the beginning but I am trying to make this an easy substitution for you.)

```
myfun[x_, y_: 0] :=
  Block[{ans, myplot, summary, Print = Sow@*Row@*List},
    Print["The first value is ", x];
    Print["The second value is ", y];
    Print["Their sum is ", x + y];
    summary = {#1, "=", #2} & @@@ Transpose[{{"x", "y"}, Round[{x, y}, 0.001]}];
    Print[Grid[summary, Alignment -> {Left, Right, Center}]];
    myplot = Plot[Sin[z], {z, -10, x}];
    Print[myplot];] // Reap // Last
```

Now using [`TableForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TableForm.html):

```
Parallelize[{myfun[1, 2], myfun[1, 4], myfun[2, 5]}] // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's indeed the easiest way for me to apply to my current code as I have lots of `Print` code among the calculations. I will try to figure out how to use `Sow` and `Reap` to replace the `Print`. I dont really see the relevance of `Composition`?

Comment: @Chen I'm glad this helps.  `Sow@*Row@*List` is another way to write `Composition[Sow, Row, List]` added in version 10.  Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: I changed a bit of the code, adopting to your solutions, it's works fine. However, just two tiny problems. In my actual code, I also Exports the `myplot` to a PDF file. In the parallel version, it only saves the first 12 PDF, among the 23 `myfun` calls. The final output in the notebook was correct. It's only the saved PDFs, there were 11 missing. I am running 8 cores. I can't seem to find out why. The last thing is, the `TableForm` makes the graph really small. Can I change something in `myplot` to make it bigger (as the normal size)?

Comment: @Chen I can't diagnose the `Export` problem without seeing some code.  Are you giving every file a unique name?  How are the names created, and which ones are missing?  For the plot size you can either wrap it in `Pane`, i.e. `Pane @ Plot[. . .]`, or specify an explicit `ImageSize` option.

Comment: @Chen I used the `Pane` method in my answer to [(11961)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11961/121) which incidentally you might find of interest.

Comment: (Cant seem to @ you) Here is the bits of the code, ` Export[ToString[HoldForm[data]]<>" -- "<>model<>".pdf",plotPI];` , where `data` and `model` are input as strings. The data are entered in random order as names of variables. The data from the letter "L" are all missing. Seems strange. I will try to fiddle around. If no success, I will start a new post. Thanks again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19153/discussion-between-chen-stats-yu-and-mr-wizard).

Comment: So I added a bit updated code, see OP. I think I understand how it works in a small example, where `Reap` collects the things in `Sow` with a tag . I dont think I fully understand how `Reap` and `Sow` works in a large piece of code, to replace `Print`.