# Annotating output without changing the value

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, output

I like to annotate output, using something like the following:

```
annotStyle[t_] := Text@Style[t, Darker@Blue, Larger]
Format[annot[t_][x_]] := Row[{annotStyle[t], annotStyle[":  "], x}]

(data = Array[RandomReal, 10]) // annot@"Ten random numbers"
{Min@data, Max@data} // annot@Range
Mean@data // annot@μ
Median@data // annot@Median
Variance@data // annot@Variance
Sqrt@%[[1]] // annot@"Standard deviation"
```

The downside is that annotating changes the value of the output. Is there some way of avoiding this, so that, for example, in the first line of the example I don't need parentheses and in the last line of the example, I don't need to use [[1]]?

> Specifically, if possible, I'd like
>
> ```
> x // annot@t
> ```
>
> to display as t:  *x*, but have the value of *x*, for any expression *x*.

As I've put this question together, I've realised that

```
annot[t_][x_] := (Print[annotStyle[t], annotStyle[":  "], x]; x;)
```

almost does what I want and is better than my previous attempt. Is there a way of getting exactly what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Based on an answer to the [duplicate question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11961/notebook-formatting-easier-descriptions-for-equations-and-results), the following, using `$PreRead` and `$PrePrint`, meets my needs, interpreting both `x // "t"` or `x; "t"` for annotations.

```
 annotStyle[t_] := Text@Style[Style[t, Darker@Blue, Larger], Larger]
 annotLine[t_, x_] := If[Characters[t][[-1]] == " ", {annotStyle[t], x}, 
   {annotStyle[t], annotStyle[Style[":  ", Bold]], x}]
 $PreRead = 
Replace[#, RowBox[{body__, ";" | "//", note_String?(StringMatchQ[#, "\"*\""] &)}] :> 
  ($note = note; RowBox[{body}])] &;
 $PrePrint = 
If[$note =!= Null, # &[Row[annotLine[ToExpression[$note], Pane@#]], 
  $note = Null], #] &;

 data = Array[RandomReal, 10]; "The random data is  "
 {Min@data, Max@data} // "Range"
 Mean@data // "μ"
 Median@data // "Median"
 Variance@data // "Variance"
 Sqrt@%[[1]] // "Standard deviation"
```