# Adding a label to an expression result

Tags: labeling, output

To make my notebook easier to read for non-Mathematica literate colleagues (myself included), I'd like to have the output from an assignment expression look somewhat more obvious.  Normally an expression assignment would look something like this:

```
In[1]= myVariable = 1 + 1

Out[1]= 2
```

But I'd like to get an output that looks more like:

```
Out[1]= myVariable = 2
```

I'm sure there are very convoluted ways to get this as an output but is there some really simple thing I can do so that the input is also still fairly easily readable without a heap of other commands wrapped around it?

Comment: I think you should look up `$Post` and `$Pre` in the _Mathematica_ documentation.

Comment: I couldn't get any joy out of `$Post` and `$PrePrint` (nuby here!).

Comment: Related: [(1047)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1047/121), [(11961)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11961/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presuming you only want to this special output to come from computations that bind a variable to the value of the computation, here is one way it can be done by `$Pre` and `$Post`:

```
SetAttributes[saveSet, HoldAll];
saveSet[form : Set[var_, _]] := (lastSet = ToString@Unevaluated@var; form);
saveSet[form : ___] := (lastSet =.; form)

$Pre = saveSet;

$Post = (If[ValueQ@lastSet, Row[{lastSet, " = ", #}], #]) &;
```

After these definitions are evaluated, computations using `Set` (=) show up as:

```
y = 42^2 + 1
```

> y = 1765

but other expression evaluations will printout normally:

```
x == y
```

> False

The downside of this is that, when these definitions are in effect, `%` becomes unusable after a `Set` evaluation. Condsider

```
y = 42^2 + 1
```

> y = 1765

```
% - 1
```

> -1+y = 1765

Comment: +1 To get around the problems with `%` not working, you could do something like the `CellPrint` code in http://stackoverflow.com/a/3947046/421225

Answer (score 9):

I'll assume that you want to echo any literal `Set` operation that occurs in input, even if it is not on a line by itself.

### `$Pre`

This may work for you:

```
$Pre =
 Function[
   main,
   Unevaluated[main] /. Set -> Function[, Print@HoldForm[# = #2]; # = #2, HoldFirst],
   HoldAll
 ];
```

Now:

```
{a = 2 + 2, b = 10/2, c = Sqrt[9]};
```

> a = 4
>
> b = 5
>
> c = 3

```
{a, b, c}
```

> ```
> {4, 5, 3}
> ```

---

### `echo` function

Alternatively, since I cannot imagine the echo being practical for *every* `Set` you might do it like this:

```
$Pre =.  (* clear the prior definition for $Pre *)

echo =
 Function[
   main,
   Unevaluated[main] /. Set -> Function[, Print@HoldForm[# = #2]; # = #2, HoldFirst],
   HoldAll
 ];
```

Then:

```
{a = 2 + 2, b = 10/2, c = Sqrt[9]} // echo
```

---

### `CellEvaluationFunction`

If you want to echo some but not all `Set`s, and you *do not* want to have `// echo` appear, you could perhaps use `CellEvaluationFunction` for individual `Cell`s.

As an example, this code generates a new input Cell into which any `Set` that is typed will be echoed:

```
CellPrint[ExpressionCell[Placeholder[], "Input", CellEvaluationFunction ->
  (ReleaseHold[
     MakeExpression@# /. 
      Set -> Function[, Print@HoldForm[# = #2]; # = #2, HoldFirst]
   ] &)
]]
```

The cell that is created can be copied and pasted to make more, or you can use the Option Inspector to set the value of `CellEvaluationFunction` for existing cells.

Comment: This works very well for my application - thankyou.

Comment: @Crusty I'm curious, if this works very well for your application why did you Accept another answer?  It is entirely your prerogative to do so, but I'm wondering in what way you found that method superior.

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest and most flexible method is to just add print statements before each operation that you want to label:

```
Print["myVariable ="];
myVariable=1+1
```

> myVariable =
>
> 2

```
Print["{M, r, T} ="];
{m=10,r=6/2,t=1/2}
```

> {M, r, T} =
>
> {10,3,1/2}

This method allows you to label expressions without the limitations of variable naming in Mathematica. For example, the following uses an ASCII variable name for a stress tensor component but labels it with the Greek characters and subscripts:

```
Print["Subscript[\[Tau], \[Phi],\[Theta]] ="];
shearPhiTheta=m/(2 \[Pi] *r^2*t)
```

> $\tau _{\phi ,\theta }\text{ =}$
>
> $\frac{10}{9 \pi }$