# Print but not evaluate with dagger

Tags: printing

I would like to print $a^\dagger$ (meaning conjugate transpose), but using Mathematica library function `ConjugateTranspose[a]` (displayed as $a^\dagger$ when typing `a Ctrl-7 Esc c t Esc`) and printing it would just yield plain text, a.k.a.

```
ConjugateTranspose[a]
```

I found a solution to replace all `ConjugateTranpose[#]` to `SuperDagger[#]`, but then it will either produce the result per se, or with `HoldForm` or `Unevaluated`, produce the expression:

```
ConjugateTranspose[a].a/.ConjugateTranspose[#]->SuperDagger[#]
```

You see, the replacement is also held.

Anyway, how can I print a daggered version of conjugate transpose?

Comment: This prints as you want. Is this what you mean?  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqhYo.png)  `ClearAll[a];
ConjugateTranspose[a] // TraditionalForm`  I did not know about `SuperDagger`. That seems to work also on V 13.1  So what exactly is the problem again? Could you post complete example that you are having problem with?

Answer (score 3):

With the help of @Nasser in the comments, I modified the code from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63068/87420).

What I want can be done by this code (Notice that I don't need tags for they can only print plain string. Hence I changed `CellPrint` to `Print`):

```
SetAttributes[verbose, HoldAll];
verbose@expr_ := 
  Module[{res = expr}, 
   If[res =!= Null, 
    Print[Unevaluated[expr // TraditionalForm], "=", 
     expr // TraditionalForm]]];
HoldPattern@verbose@Set[lhs_, rhs_] := 
  Print[Unevaluated[lhs // TraditionalForm], 
   "=", (lhs = rhs) // TraditionalForm];
$Pre = verbose;
```

Execute this code, then evaluating variables will print their values with the expression or the LHS of the assignment.